# scala spark reducebykey use custom fuction

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to use `reducebykey` but when i try to use it, it show error:

> type miss match required Nothing

question: How can I create a custom function for `reducebykey`?

{(key,value)}

key:string
value: map

example:

```
rdd = {("a", "weight"->1), ("a", "weight"->2)}
expect{("a"->3)}

def combine(x: mutable.map[string,Int],y:mutable.map[string,Int]):mutable.map[String,Int]={
    x.weight = x.weithg+y.weight
    x
}
    
rdd.reducebykey((x,y)=>combine(x,y))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a `RDD[(K, V)]` (or `PairRDD[K, V]` to be more accurate) and you want to somehow combine values with same `key` then you can use `reduceByKey` which expects a function `(V, V) => V` and gives you the modified `RDD[(K, V)]`  (or `PairRDD[K, V]`)

Here, your `rdd = {("a", "weight"->1), ("a", "weight"->2)}` is not real Scala and similary the whole combine function is wrong both syntactically and logically (it will not compile). But I am guessing that what you have is something like following,

```scala
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(
  ("a", "weight"->1),
  ("a", "weight"->2)
))
```

Which means that your rdd is of type `RDD[(String, (String, Int))]` or `PairRDD[String, (String, Int)]` which means that `reduceByKey` wants a function of type `((String, Int), (String, Int)) => (String, Int)`.

```scala
def combine(x: (String, Int), y: (String, Int])): (String, Int) =
  (x._1, x._2 + y._2)

val rdd2 = rdd.reducebykey(combine)
```

If your problem is something else then please update the question to share your problem with real code, so that others can actually understand it.

Comment: how about if the value is map, because the value is not only weight->1, it is a complicate map

Comment: Can you provide actual scala code which accurately describes your problem ? And why will you even need a `mutable map` in an RDD ?

Comment: thanks think i have solve the problem, my problem is when i use row.getAs("something"), but didn't declare the Type, should be row.getAs[Map]("something")

Comment: And now you are talking about `Row` which means that you were actually dealing with `DataFrame` and not RDD's.

Comment: i mean when i transfer DF to rdd[k,v] pair, i didn't declare the v's type, that's why my reducebykey can not work